# Forward Windows Events Logs to Rsyslog

Tags: linux, windows, syslog, windows-event-log, rsyslog

I would like to forward Windows Events Logs from all my desktop clients to a Linux box with rsyslog on.

Rsyslog provide a Windows agent to do just that but its 40 euros per license and when you have x amount of machines that cost adds up.

I was wondering if there is a FOSS alternative available I have tried searching the Google but haven't managed to find anything.

Hopefully someone might already faced this same problem and are using an alternative that they could recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`Snare Agent for
   Windows`](http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/SnareWindows/index.html)
2. [`Datagram
   SyslogAgent`](http://www.syslogserver.com/syslogagent.html)
3. [`eventlog-to-syslog`](http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/)

Answer (score 6):

You might be also interested in [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) as it provides a wealth of features such as rfc5424 syslog format, TLS/SSL, filtering, rewrite, etc. (note: I'm affiliated with the project).